# Fast algorithm to count the number of 1 for binary number

Tags: algorithm

1. If I have binary number  0111000111111,
   Is there any fast algorithm to count the number of 1 ?
2. If 0111000111111 is a string(e.g "0111000111111")
   Is there any fast algorithm to count the number of 1 in the string?

Answer (score 2):

A relatively fast way is to precompute a table of the bit counts for all byte values and to sum for the four bytes of the (unsigned) integer.

```
byte NB[256]= { 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, ... };

N= NB[U & 255] + NB[(U >> 8) & 255] + NB[(U >> 16) & 255] + NB[(U >> 24) & 255];
```

You can adapt this for different numbers of bits per slice.

Comment: Sorry,but I couldn't understand this pre-computed table!

Comment: 0 = 00000000 -> 0; 1 = 00000001 -> 1; 2 = 00000010 -> 1; 3 = 00000011 -> 2; 4 = 00000100 -> 1 ...

Comment: @YvesDaoust-Ahh,Thanks,+1!